# DI/IOC for .NET Framework 2.0

Tags: .net, c#-2.0, ioc-container

Please, advise good DI/IOC for .NET Framework 2.0. The customer requires this version of .NET framework.

Have a nice day!

Comment: does the client actually want just 2.0, or are 3.0 and 3.5 good as well, as they run in the 2.0 runtime?

Comment: Client wants only 2.0, and i don't know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a huge fan of [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/) as an IoC container.

The current version is only for .NET 3.5 and 4.0, but you'll find that the [previous versions](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/downloads/list?can=1&q=.NET%202.0) were designed with .NET 2.0 in mind.

My company uses Autofac 1.3 in a number of .NET 2.0 applications, and have found it to be a very powerful IoC container.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should get the book "Dependency Injection in .NET"

http://www.manning.com/seemann/

it is available as an early-access edition and contains a comparison of different DI containers for .NET. This (german) site

http://www.clean-code-developer.de/Tools.ashx

contains a list of links to different DI / IOC containers. Hope this helps.

Comment: For .NET 3.5/4.0 I use Autofac, but Autofac build for .NET 2.0 doesn't have some features, that I need.

Comment: @meridian: your comment was addressed to Joviee's answer, right? And if you have specific requirements, why don't you list them in your question?

Comment: @meridian which features are you looking for? They often have different APIs in the 1.x series of releases to the 2.x series.